# How is on campus professional training named in US or Canada schools?

Tags: university, undergraduate

I'm applying for a scholarship abroad (more specifically, in Canada), and I have a doubt concerning how to write of the activities I took part on my CV.

In my home institution, we have activities called "Professional Training". These are some jobs students can take part inside of the university, outside of their degree coursework, under guidance of one of the professors, usually something for the university. For example, a biology student could help taking care of a botanical garden they have on campus, or a computer science student could help maintaining the university website. Students gain some hands on experience from these activities, receiving some money for it every month, while helping the university on some of its duties.

I took part in one of those activities for over a year, and I find it very relevant for the scholarship that I'm applying, so I'm detailing it on my CV. However, I'm not sure how to properly name it. I don't know if US or Canadian schools have anything like that. I don't think "internship" is the proper name, because it's not related to industry. Also "teaching assistant" obviously doesn't fit, because it could have nothing to do with teaching.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's anything wrong with calling these "internships."  If you are concerned about the possibility of confusion, you may say "university internship."  As you will also be identifying the campus office you worked for, the situation should be clear.